# В параграфе не подсвечиваются теги. Редактор Atom. В чём дело?

Tags: html5, atom, теги, выделение-текста

В длинном параграфе необходимо было везде подчеркнуть пунктиром слово HTML, до определённого момента теги подсвечиваются красным, но в конце параграфа подсветка пропадает и они отображаются серым цветом. Что тут не так, ребят?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<p>
  <span class="пунктир">HTML</span> elements are the building blocks of <span class="пунктир">HTML</span> pages. With <span class="пунктир">HTML</span> constructs, images and other objects such as interactive forms may be embedded into the rendered page. <span class="пунктир">HTML</span> provides a means to create structured documents by denoticg structural semantics for text such as headings, paragraphs, lists, links, quotes and other items. <span class="пунктир">HTML</span> elements are delineated by tags, written using angle brackets. Tags such as <kbd>&lt;img /&gt;</kbd> and <kbd>&lt;input /&gt;</kbd> directly introduce content into the page. Other tags such as <kbd>&lt;p&gt;</kbd> surround and provide information about document text and may include other tags as sub-elements. Browsers do not display the <span class="пунктир">HTML</span> tags, but use them to interpret the content of the page.
</p>
```

Comment: Видимо строка для обработки ограничивается длиной. Вставьте перенос строки после слов `quotes and other items.` и должно заработать.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал другой редактор: WebStorm или VS Code. И данную операцию можно сделать простым `replace`. Например:
`<p id="pId">
</p>
<script>
  var text = "HTML elements are the building blocks of ";
  text = text.replace("HTML", "<button class=\"button btn-block\">HTML</button>");
  console.log(text);
  document.getElementById("pId").innerHTML = text;
</script>`

Comment: @MikhailIonkin, вы проверили подсветку в других редакторах?

Comment: @РустамГимранов да. В WebStorm  нормально отображаются все теги.

Comment: @MikhailIonkin вот спасибо большое за VS Code. Я только начал кодить, выбирал из разных редакторов, потом появилась проблема с Atom, а VS Code это супер приложение, очень удобно